# Javascript function properties

Tags: javascript

Why is it that I can do the following in javascript:

```
function a() {};
a.foo = 30;
```

Specifically, why can I set a property on the function a? After all, I cannot do this:

```
var a = 20;
a.foo = 30;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really can't do this because it's a syntax error

```
function a = function() {};
```

I suppose you simply want to say:

```
function a() {}
```

Anyway. The reason that you cannot get a property out of a number, is that it is not a real Object.

```
a = 20;
a.foo = 30;   // this works
alert(a.foo); // this alerts nothing
```

Believe it or not, the same goes for strings:

```
a = "ohai";
a.foo = 30;   // this works
alert(a.foo); // this alerts nothing
```

However if it's String object, then it works as expected:

```
a = new String("ohai");
a.foo = 30;   // this works
alert(a.foo); // this alerts 30
```

Or if it's an Number object. You get the point.

String and number literals are not objects in Javascript. That's the reason.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript the dot (**.**) operator expects it's left value to be an object. And in JavaScript, functions are objects.

Basically, in JavaScript, there are four main datatypes:

1. Number
2. String
3. Boolean
4. Object

*Objects* encompasses functions, arrays, date objects, and (for lack of a better word) *regular* objects. The function object is unique in that it contains **executable code**, and can be **invoked**.

Numbers are primitives, and thus you cannot access/assign properties to/from them.

Comment: there's Arrays too... they have different native prototypes than Objects (note that an Array will return a typeof as an object, but if you check its constructor you will see that it is in fact `Array`).

Comment: @Peter: Still, Arrays are objects. The ECMA standard defines "Array objects", "Function objects", ... and "Object objects"

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, a function is an object, so you can set properties on it:

```
function a() {};
a.foo = 30;
a.foo; // evaluates to 30
```

A number literal however creates a *primitive value* (which has no properties) and not an *object*.

```
a = 20;       // Create primitive value using number literal
```

When you set a property on a primitive value, in fact you create a *wrapper object* around the primitive value and set the property on the wrapper object, not the primitive value.

```
a.foo = 30;               // wrapper object created and directly thrown away
(new Number(a)).foo = 30; // --> equivalent
```

When you read the property, again you create a wrapper object, whihch hasn't the property defined.

```
a.foo;                    // wrapper object created, has no foo property
(new Number(a)).foo;      // --> equivalent, evaluates to undefined
```

Comment: In Javascript, a function is an object, so you can set properties on it ... nice!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript functions are objects. Or they inherit from objects, or something.

try doing

```
a = function(){};
alert(typeof a.prototype);
```